# c# Checking if row exists when synchronizing two tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, ado.net, synchronization

I am trying to sync two tables from a Sql Server database and MySql database. I have an application with both database models using ADO.NET, which provides a WCF service to send the data from the MySql database to the SqlServer database. In the service consumer i have the following code which:

1. Calls the proxy method every 5 seconds.
2. Uses an asynchronous call.

   ```
   private void proxy_DoWorkCompleted(object sender, DoWorkCompletedEventArgs e)
   {

       dbEntities db = new dbEntities(); //local db object

       foreach (var item in e.Result)
       {
           if (!db.Table.Any(x => x.someID == item.some_id)) //This line is supposed to check for existing entries 
           {
               db.Table.Add(new Something()
               {
                   ID = item.some_id,
                   Name = item.name,
                   Description = item.description,
                   ....
               });
               db.SaveChanges();
           }
       }

   }
   ```

The problem i have is that the if statement is not giving me what i expect and i get a Primary Key Violation Exception. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If I am reading this right, I think you have the logic backwards. If the ID's match you *don't* want to insert a record correct?

Comment: yes that's right. @JacobH